# Material UI - How to ListItem link to open a dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'll preface with the fact I am pretty green on React.

I have a dynamic list of employee items inside a `Card` component as part of a dashboard. 
I want to add the ability to create a link per employee, clicking on the link will open a modal dialog to enable  editing in the same page.

I am not so sure how to go about making the connection between the ListItem->Link->EmployeeEdit functionality to ensure that I am passing the right props at every step of the way.

So I have this so far to show the employees in a list of links but not sure how to create the relationship to render the EmployeeEdit component:

LIST:

```
    <List dense={true}>
        {(Array.isArray(employees) && employees.length != 0 )  ? employees.map(employee => {
            const LinkToEdit = ({props}) => <Link {...props} record={employee}/>;
            return(
            <ListItem
                key={employee.id}
                button
                component={LinkToEdit}
            >
                <ListItemText
                    primary={
                        `${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}`
                    }
                    secondary={translate('tequiti.entity.joined_date', {
                        createdAt: new Date(employee.createdAt).toLocaleString('en-US')
                    })}

                />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction/>
            </ListItem>
            )
        }) : <p>No employees for this company</p>
        }
    </List>
```

EDITEMPLOYEE:

```
const EmployeeEdit = (props) => {
    const translate = useTranslate();
    const [state, setState] = useState({showEditDialog: true});
    let {showEditDialog} = state;
    const handleCloseEditClick = () => {
        setState({
            showEditDialog: false
        });
    };
    return(
        <Dialog
            fullWidth
            open={showEditDialog}
            modal={ true }
            onClose={handleCloseEditClick}
            aria-label="Edit Employee"
            {...props}
        >
            <DialogTitle>Edit Employee</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <TabbedForm resource="employee" toolbar={<UpdateActions {...props} />}>
                    <FormTab label={translate('root.label.identity')}>
                        <PersonInput />
                    </FormTab>
                    <FormTab label={translate('root.label.address')}>
                        <AddressInput />
                    </FormTab>
                </TabbedForm>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button label="ra.action.cancel" onClick={() => handleCloseEditClick()}>
                    <IconCancel />
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
)};
```

Any suggestions/help would be great!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add (SOLVED) or edit an answer into your question. If you found an answer you received helpful in solving your problem, you can do so by clicking the checkbox next to the question, which tells everyone that you've found a solution. If you found the answer yourself and want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. You can find more information in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you have a `Dialog` modal for every employee (i.e., the `EmployeeEdit` component). I'd probably simplify this to have a single `EmployeeEdit` component on the page, and have a an `employee` property it accepts. If there is an employee property, show the dialog for that employee. If the `employee` propert is falsey, hide the dialog. Then you can just have an `onClick` for your list items that sets the current employee. So something like this (simplified for brevity):

```
const EmployeeEdit = ({employee, onClose, onChange, ...props}) => {
  const showDialog = Boolean(employee)
  //use onClose and onChange as appropriate
  ...
}
const EmployeeList = ({employees}) => {
  const [currentEmployee, setCurrentEmployee] = useState(null);
  const clearEmployee = () => {
    setCurrentEmployee(null)
  }
  const handleChange = (employee) => {
    //do something with the results, probably update employees array,
    //then close dialog by clearing the current employee
    setCurrentEmployee(null)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <EmployeeEdit employee={currentEmployee} onClose={clearEmployee} onChange={handleChange}/>
      {employees.map(e => {
        <ListItem onClick={() => setCurrentEmloyee(e)} />
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you did there and I like that pattern much better.